# Expected time for both people to finish a job

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Al and Betty are each working independently on a project starting at
the same time. The time to completion for Al is uniformly distributed on
[0, 2] hours and for Betty is uniformly distributed on [0, 1] hours. They will
go home together when both have finished. Let T be the time to when they
have both finished. Find the density function for T and find the expected
value of T.

My attempt: $$\text{Al: }F_X(x)=P(X<x)=\int^x_0\frac{1}{2}dx$$
$$\text{Betty: }F_Y(y)=P(Y<y)=\int^y_01dy$$
$$F_{X,Y}(x,y)=\int\int\frac{1}{2}dxdy$$
$$T=\max\{X,Y\}$$
$$P(T<t)=P(\max\{X,Y\}<t)$$
$$=1-\int_t^1\int_t^2\frac{1}{2}dxdy=\frac{3t-t^2}{2}$$
since $t>\max\{X,Y\}\Rightarrow t>X,t>Y$.
$$f_T(t)=\frac{3-2t}{2},0\leq t\leq1$$
$$E(T)=\int_0^1t\cdot f_T(t)dt=\frac{5}{12}$$

Is my reasoning, and my answer, correct, or am I way off? I had a lot of trouble with this problem and am unsure that I did it correctly.

Comment: this is clearly incorrect since your distribution $(3t-t^2)/2$ is not monotonically increasing on $[0,2]$.

Comment: the distribution for the max is the probability that both random variables are less than $t$, so you need to take the product of the single integrals instead of computing the double integral.  i.e. $P(\max(X,Y)<t) = P(X,Y < t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly if Al takes more than 1 hour, Betty will certainly have finished.   And so the CDF will be a piecewise function, and so shall the pdf.

$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(\max(X,Y)\leq t) & = \mathsf P(X\leq t, Y\leq t)
\\[1ex] & = \int_0^{\min(1,t)}\int_0^{\min(2,t)} \tfrac 1 2 \operatorname d x\operatorname d y\cdot\mathbf 1_{t\in[0;2)}+\mathbf 1_{t\in[2;\infty)}
\\[1ex] & = \tfrac 1 2\int_0^{\min(1,t)} t \operatorname d y\cdot\mathbf 1_{t\in[0;2)}+\mathbf 1_{t\in[2;\infty)}
\\[1ex] & = \frac{t^2}{2}\mathbf 1_{t\in[0;1)}+\frac{t}{2}\mathbf 1_{t\in[1;2)}+\mathbf 1_{t\in[2;\infty)}
\end{align}$

Hence:
$$F_T(t) = \begin{cases}0 & : t< 0 \\ t^2/2 & : 0\leq t < 1 &\\ t/2 & : 1\leq t< 2 \\ 1 & : 2\leq t \end{cases}
$$

Now use $\newcommand{\Int}{{\displaystyle\int}}\mathsf E(T) = \Int_0^2 (1-F_T(t))\operatorname d t \\ \qquad = \Int_0^1 1-t^2/2\operatorname d t + \Int_1^2 1-t/2\operatorname d t$ (since $T$ is strictly non-negative.)

Comment: Does the notation $\mathbf 1$ refer to the different regions $t$ can belong to? And how can $t$ belong to $[2,\infty)$ if Al and Betty are distributed over [0,2] and [0,1], respectively?

Comment: Oh, never mind, I see why $F_T(t)$ is defined for $t\geq2$

Comment: Yes, the indicator function is a piecewise function defined as one when the subscript is true, and zero otherwise. $$\mathbf 1_{t\in A} = \begin{cases}1 & : t\in A \\ 0 & : t\notin A\end{cases}$$  Cumulative Distribution Functions are defined as $1$ when the argument exceeds the supremum of the random variable's support.

Comment: Thank you!
One more question: isn't the expected value supposed to be found using the PDF(f_T(t)), and not the CDF (F_T(t))?

Comment: Well, you can first derive the pdf then use it, @MattG .  However, for *strictly-non-negative* random-variables, there is a famous result using [Fubini's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) that:  $$\begin{align}\int_0^\infty 1-F_X(y)\operatorname d y & = \int_0^\infty \int_y^\infty f_X(x)\operatorname d x\operatorname d y \\ & = \int_0^\infty \int_0^x f_X(x) \operatorname d y\operatorname d x \\ & = \int_0^\infty x f_X(x)\operatorname d x \\ & =\mathsf E(X)\end{align}$$